# How to call a operator overloaded function from other functions / methods in c++?

Tags: c++, class, object, methods, operator-overloading

I have another class object in my class. Ex:

**ParkingMeter.h**

```
class ParkingMeter
{
private:
    ParkedCar pCar;
    int minutesPurchased = 0;

public:   
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream, ParkingMeter&);   
};
```

**ParkedCar.h**

```
class ParkedCar
{
private:
    std::string maker;
    std::string model;
    std::string color;
    int licenseNumber = 0;
    int minutesParked = 0;

public:
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, ParkedCar&);
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, ParkedCar&);
};
```

So, when I enter the data for **ParkingMeter** object with it's respective operator overloaded, I want to call the overloaded function for the **ParkedCar** object aswell.

This is what I've got. The operator overloaded function for the **ParkingMeter**:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream is, ParkingMeter& obj)
{
    cout << "How many minutes to buy? ";
    is >> obj.minutesPurchased;

    cout << "Enter the information about your car:\n";
    is >> obj.pCar;

    return is;
}
```

But in my main file, the following code don't word:

```
ParkingMeter temp;
std::cin >> temp;
```

Thank you.

---

***Solution***

Thanks to @L. F. for pointing my silly mistake. :D

I've forgotten to use the **&** after *std::istream* in the arguments for the function:

```
friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream, ParkingMeter&);
```

Now its works fine:

```
friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, ParkingMeter&);
```

Comment: What is the obstacle?

Comment: I've edited the question. See the last bit. Thanks! :)

Comment: OK, you need to change `std::istream is` to `std::istream& is` first.

Comment: That was it. Sorry for wasting your time. That was silly. Thanks so much! :D

Comment: The extraction operators are not supposed to interact with the user in any way. Suppose you wanted to read ten parking meters from an input file – would you really like to see those prompts flash by ten times?